# Extract only XML from a string response

Tags: java, xml, regex, string, parsing

I'm getting a XML response along with call stack values in a HTTP response. I'm successfully able to parse the XML. However having trouble with extracting the XML first. Below is the XML I want to extract.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <response
 status="ok"><token>af53bd59811111</token></response>
```

from the following string which is a httpresponse. I tried string RegEx a bit, could not proceed.

```
Notice: Undefined index: Content-type in /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/API/Service/File/Abstract.php on line 251

Call Stack:
    0.0001     645184   1. {main}() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/www/index.php:0
    0.0374    7276184   2. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/www/index.php:10
    0.0426    8577512   3. Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:946
    0.0454    8972072   4. Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:289
    0.0454    8977384   5. FileController->indexAction() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php:513
    0.0526   10124216   6. Zend_Rest_Server->handle() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/controllers/index/FileController.php:41
    0.0527   10130800   7. Zend_Rest_Server->_callObjectMethod() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Rest/Server.php:228
    0.0528   10131864   8. Zend_Server_Reflection_Method->invokeArgs() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Rest/Server.php:603
    0.0528   10132304   9. Zend_Server_Reflection_Function_Abstract->__call() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Rest/Server.php:603
    0.0528   10132744  10. call_user_func_array() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Server/Reflection/Function/Abstract.php:368
    0.0528   10133272  11. API_Service_File->address() /data/home/web/src/ZendFramework-1.9.5-modified/library/Zend/Server/Reflection/Function/Abstract.php:0
    0.0705   12262480  12. API_Service_File_Abstract->handle() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/API/Service/File.php:30
    0.0705   12262480  13. API_Service_File_Address->post() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/API/Service/File/Abstract.php:52
    0.0705   12262480  14. API_Service_File_Abstract->_post() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/API/Service/File/Address.php:61
    0.0705   12262696  15. API_Service_File_Abstract->_rawUpload() /data/home/web/src/api_API_Stage_381_201404171313/API/Service/File/Abstract.php:147

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response status="ok"><token>af53bd59811111</token></response>
```

XML was parsed and token was captured by XML parser below

```
            responseXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <response status=\"ok\"><token>af53bd598f5a411</token></response>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        InputSource inputsource;

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            inputsource = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXml));
            Document doc = builder.parse(inputsource);
            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("token");
            System.out.println("Got Token!! -" + list.item(0).getTextContent());
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the String.indexOf(String) method to locate the start position of the XML in the HttpResponse, then String.substring(int) to extract the XML, for example:

```
    String responseXml = response.substring(response.indexOf("<?xml"));
```